# Can style be saved with Qpackage and how can the new .qgs use the new .shp locations automatically?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, style, layer-package

I've used the Qpackage plugin to move all the layers of a project to a new location. At first my try was to move the source files, but it seems to have made new files, which is no problem.
But now it seems the .qgs on the new location doesn't automaticly use these new layer files. When I load in one of the files the style is also not the same as from the original file. Can I use Qpackage to save/move style files as well? And is there a way to make the new .qgs automaticly use the newly made files for the layers as well? Or do I have to change the source file for all the layers manualy.
I'm used to the packaging mechanics of Adobe Indesign, so the QGIS way of packaging isn't very logical to me.

Comment: Have you saved separate style files (`.qml`)? Usually Qgis saves the layer style in the project file, so you should move this as well and all should be fine. Are you working with absolute or relative paths? How do the old and new locations differ when it comes to folder structure?

Comment: I didn't save the .qml, I'll look up how to. Is it possible to have Qgis automaticly make a .qml file? I'm working with relative paths, should I change it to absolute paths? The original layers have datasources in multiple backups. Each backup has a folder but they are in the same folder with the .qgz. I have backups from around 15 days of fieldwork, and every few days I would work with the files to connect polygons and such. But not all the files would be used, only the ones that had more data from before, or i would copy paste the new data to old layers.

Comment: With packaging it has created new files, which are all located in one folder. This folder is located in a different drive. Though I think the same happens when I would save it to the same drive als the .qgz is saved.

Comment: If you work with relative path, you could simply copy the "old" project-file to the new location (while observing to keep the same relative path) and everything should be fine.

Comment: But that would mean I always have to keep all those backups right? I was hoping I could just use only the new files for my project. So I can storage the original files (backups) somewhere externally. Cause it will save us quite a bit of space when we have to do this for 30+ more projects. But from what I understand now I always have to keep the link to the original files?

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to have someone take a direct look at your data structure and what you're doing. Because right now we're just throwing guesses.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help